# Is this a BSP tree? Am I missing something?

Tags: tree, lua, computational-geometry, clustering

I've been practicing using BSP trees as I hear they are a good start to create procedural spaces such as houses.

For ease-of-deployment purposes, I've tested this code in Lua and it seems to work.  However, I want to confirm if I did what I needed to do instead of something else. When I am sure this works I will properly implement it in C.

This would be the code:

```
MAX_RECURSION = 3
TL = 1
BL = 2
BR = 3
TR = 4


grid = {}
grid.w = 60;
grid.h = 12;
grid.max = grid.w * grid.h
grid.pos = function (self, x, y) return (x * self.w + y)+1 end
grid.get = function (self, x, y) return self.data[self:pos(x, y)] end
grid.set = function (self, x, y, d) self.data[self:pos(x,y)] = d end
grid.data = {}
for i = 1, grid.max do grid.data[i] = " " end

rooms = 1

function node_c(parent, rect)
    n = {}
    n.child1 = nil
    n.child2 = nil
    n.parent = parent
    n.rect = rect
    n.w = rect[TR].x-rect[TL].x
    n.h = rect[BL].y-rect[TL].y if n.h < 0 then n.h = 0 end
    n.level = parent.level + 1
    n.id = 0
    n.vertical = direction_get(n)
    node_draw(n)
    return n
end

function rootnode(rect)
    n = {}
    n.child1 = nil
    n.child2 = nil
    n.rect = rect
    n.parent = nil
    n.w = rect[TR].x-rect[TL].x
    n.h = rect[BL].y-rect[TL].y
    n.level = 0
    n.id = 0
    n.vertical = direction_get(n)
    node_draw(n)
    return n
end

function node_draw(node)
    local x, y
    local rect = node.rect
    for y = rect[TL].y, rect[BL].y do
        for x = rect[TL].x, rect[TR].x do
            if x==rect[TL].x or x==rect[TR].x or y==rect[TL].y or y==rect[BR].y then
                grid:set(x, y, "#")
            else
                grid:set(x, y, ".")
            end
        end
    end
end

function node_split(node)
    if not node or not (node.level < MAX_RECURSION) then
        node.id = rooms
        rooms = rooms + 1
        return
    else
        local p
        if node.vertical then p = "X" else p = "Y" end
        local split = node_splitfrom(node)
        if split == nil then return end
        local c1, c2, r1, r2
        r1,r2 = node_rects(node, split)
        node.child1 = node_c(node, r1)
        node.child2 = node_c(node, r2)
        --draw_it(grid)
        node_split(node.child1)
        node_split(node.child2)
    end
end

function direction_get(node)
    if math.random(0, 1) == 0 then return true else return false end
end

function node_splitfrom(node)
    local result
    if node.vertical then
        local r = math.floor(((math.random(20, 80)/100) * node.w))
        if r < 2 or r > node.w - 2 then return nil else return node.rect[TL].x + r end
    else
        local r = math.floor(((math.random(20, 80)/100) * node.h))
        if r < 2 or r > node.h - 2 then return nil else return node.rect[TL].y + r end
    end
end

function print_rect(rect)
    return "TL:"..rect[TL].x..","..rect[TL].y.." BL:"..rect[BL].x..","..rect[BL].y.." BR:"..rect[BR].x..","..rect[BR].y.." TR:"..rect[TR].x..","..rect[TR].y
end

function node_rects(node, split)
    local rect1, rect2
    local t
    t = node.rect
    if node.vertical then
        rect1 = {[TL] = t[TL], [BL] = t[BL], [TR] = {x=split,y=t[TR].y}, [BR] = {x=split,y=t[BR].y}}
        rect2 = {[TL] = {x=split,y=t[TL].y}, [BL] = {x=split,y=t[BL].y}, [TR] = t[TR], [BR] = t[BR]}
        return rect1,rect2
    else
        rect1 = {[TL]=t[TL],[TR] = t[TR],[BL]={x=t[BL].x,y=split}, [BR]={x=t[BR].x,y=split}}
        rect2 = {[TL]={x=t[TL].x,y=split},[TR]={x=t[TR].x,y=split},[BL]=t[BL],[BR] = t[BR]}
        return rect1,rect2
    end
end

function bsp_it(g)
    local rect = { --Counter clockwise
        [TL] = {x=0,y=0},
        [BL] = {x=0,y=g.h},
        [BR] = {x=g.w,y=g.h},
        [TR] = {x=g.w,y=0}
    }
    local root = rootnode(rect)
    node_split(root)
    return root
end

function print_it(t)
    if(t) then
        local spaces = (t.level * 2)
        local i
        local space = ""
        for i = 0, spaces do space = space.." " end
        if not t.parent then print(space.."#"..("%X"):format(t.id)) else print(space.."\\"..("%X"):format(t.id)) end
        print_it(t.child1) print_it(t.child2)
    end
end

function draw_it(grid)
    local line = ""
    local x,y
    for y = 0, grid.h do
        for x = 0, grid.w do
            line = ""..line..(grid.data[grid:pos(x,y)] or 0)
        end
        print(line)
        line = ""
    end
end

math.randomseed(os.time())

test = bsp_it(grid, 3)
print_it(test)
draw_it(grid)
```

This is a very naive approach. I don't check for size ratio or anything to make it look good and I am not connecting the rooms yet (I will deal with it later. A table recursively collecting the nodes should do the work).

So the question is if this is actually a BSP tree, and if I am missing something important in here.

Additionally, having this data, how should I check for connectivity among individual rooms? Picking a node, check parent and connect all nodes inside parent, perhaps?

Answer (score 7):

Your principal algorithm is a correctly implemented BSP, so yes. You are creating a Binary Space Partitioning tree.

Also, FWIW: You only need two points on opposing corners to define an axis aligned rectangle which you seem to be using here. So you could simplify.

**Edit:** Just noticed your question about connectivity:

Just checking the immediate parent will give you a subset of the possible connection information. Since your BSP is axis aligned and 2 dimensional each node can have 1 to 4 neighboring nodes (depending on if it's positioned along the edges or not) or 0 for the root but lets ignore the root because it's not interesting.

If you're interested in the full connectivity you can either traverse the tree top down and keep track of all edges and in that way find which rooms are neighboring. Or you can keep track of north,west,east,south neighbor of a node during tree generation and use this information to determine connectivity.

If you only look at the immediate parent, you only get one connecting node (out of possibly 4). I do not know how you intend to use this connectivity information so this may be enough for you.